# Kuberentes client-go method to drain a node

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

Is there a go client to drain a Kubernetes node.
I am writing E2E testcases using existing kubernetes E2E framework and i need to cover a node drain scenario for storage.

Comment: No, there is not. But one can write his/her own logic to drain a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a method in client-go to facilitate draining. I believe that there is some work to bring that functionality to client-go, but it's not there yet. That being said you can base an E2E test case on the drain code found at:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/tree/master/pkg/drain